# Recreating default constraint - new constraint does not match

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, constraints

I've scripted & run a default constraint to recreate it:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableName] ADD  CONSTRAINT 
[DF_TableName_TableNameID]  DEFAULT (convert(uniqueidentifier,(convert(binary(10),newid()) + convert(binary(6),getdate())))) FOR [TableNameID]
```

When I check the table, it now looks like this:

```
[DF_TableName_TableNameID]  DEFAULT (CONVERT([uniqueidentifier],CONVERT([binary](10),newid(),0)+CONVERT([binary](6),getdate(),0),0))
```

Is there any particular reason it has changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constraints are "compiled" down into their simplest form, and the original text used to create the constraint is thrown away. The value you're seeing when checking the table is the simplest way of expressing the same constraint. You'll also find that you can't save (for example) comments in constraints.

Comment: Thanks Damien - it is a little irritating as I'm recreating the database using SMO then checking with SQL compare - and getting a boatload of errors. Ah well :)